# SQL 2016 Installation Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to install sql 2016 standard on a windows server 2012 standard edition, and I am running into an odd error, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. I am getting account validation errors after putting in the domain account information, to run the database engine, the agent, and ssrs.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zuxl.jpg)

Here what I believe is the pertinent section of the setup log

```
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: SQLEngine : Validating Engine Service Account 
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to determine if the account 'my_domain\engine_account' is Virtual Account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to determine if the account 'my_domain\engine_account' is Managed Service Account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : Attempting to get account sid for account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account from sid S-1-5-21-2054966371-109381095-1963001494-235403
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to initialize user group my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if user group engine_account exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open root DirectoryEntry object for domain/computer 'my_domain'
(13) 2016-06-30 15:43:56 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if container 'WinNT://my_domain' of group exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: User group engine_account doesn't exist
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : Service Acccount Specified, Validating Password
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to validate credentials for user account 'my_domain\engine_account' and service name 'MSSQLSERVER'
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to determine if the account 'my_domain\engine_account' is Virtual Account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to see if user my_domain\engine_account exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco.User.OpenRoot - Attempting to get root DirectoryEntry for domain/computer 'my_domain'
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if user account my_domain\engine_account exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to look up AD entry for user my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco.User.OpenRoot - root DirectoryEntry object already opened for this computer for this object
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco.User.LookupADEntry - Attempting to find user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to check if container 'WinNT://my_domain' of user account exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: User my_domain\engine_account located
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account from sid S-1-5-21-2054966371-109381095-1963001494-235403
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Check success - user my_domain\engine_account exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidatePassword -- validating user:  my_domain\engine_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidatePassword -- user validation failed, attempting an interactive logon in case cached credentials are present
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidateCredentials -- user validation failed
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validation for account my_domain\engine_account failed. The credentials you provided for the 'MSSQLSERVER' service is invalid.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Action Scenario: Install, Feature Scenario: Install, Resolved Scenario Install 
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating System Data Directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if directory UNC Path
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if drive is valid
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --SqlEngineSetupPrivate: EngineBasePrivateConfig tries to retrieve product property ClusterActionState while the based class was not properly initialized.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : File system for folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA is NTFS
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating Default Data Directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if directory UNC Path
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if drive is valid
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --SqlEngineSetupPrivate: EngineBasePrivateConfig tries to retrieve product property ClusterActionState while the based class was not properly initialized.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : File system for folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA is NTFS
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating Default Transaction Log Directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if directory UNC Path
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if drive is valid
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --SqlEngineSetupPrivate: EngineBasePrivateConfig tries to retrieve product property ClusterActionState while the based class was not properly initialized.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : File system for folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA is NTFS
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating Backup Directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if directory UNC Path
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if drive is valid
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --SqlEngineSetupPrivate: EngineBasePrivateConfig tries to retrieve product property ClusterActionState while the based class was not properly initialized.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : File system for folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup is NTFS
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating Security Mode
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Checking for existing system databases.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Action Scenario: Install, Feature Scenario: Install, Resolved Scenario Install 
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: Validating tempdb file count: SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT = 8
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: Validating tempdb file size settings: SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE = 8, SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH = 64, SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE = 8, SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH = 64
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating TempDB Data Directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if directory UNC Path
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if drive is valid
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --SqlEngineSetupPrivate: EngineBasePrivateConfig tries to retrieve product property ClusterActionState while the based class was not properly initialized.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : File system for folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA is NTFS
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Validating TempDB Log Directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if directory UNC Path
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine: Checking if drive is valid
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --SqlEngineSetupPrivate: EngineBasePrivateConfig tries to retrieve product property ClusterActionState while the based class was not properly initialized.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Engine : File system for folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA is NTFS
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Checking for existing tempdb file tempdb.mdf.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Checking for existing tempdb file templog.ldf.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get directory information for path C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Checking for existing tempdb files tempdb_mssql_*.ndf.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 SQLEngine: --InputValidator: Checking AddCurrentUserAsSQLAdmin setting.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to format the virtual account name from service name 'ReportServer'
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to validate credentials for user account 'my_domain\service_account' and service name 'ReportServer'
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to determine if the account 'my_domain\service_account' is Virtual Account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get account sid for user account my_domain\service_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get sid for user account my_domain\service_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Attempting to see if user my_domain\service_account exists
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco.User.OpenRoot - root DirectoryEntry object already opened for this computer for this object
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: Sco: Check already done for user my_domain\service_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidatePassword -- validating user:  my_domain\service_account
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidatePassword -- user validation failed, attempting an interactive logon in case cached credentials are present
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidateCredentials -- user validation failed
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 RS: The credentials you provided for the Reporting Services service are invalid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the Reporting Services service.
(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 RS: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Sco.InvalidPrincipalNameException: The credentials you provided for the 'ReportServer' service is invalid.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.RSExtension.SQLRSConfigurationPublic.IsValidServiceAccount(ServiceContainer context, String userName, SqlSecureString password)
```

From looking at the log, it looks like the installation was able to find the account in AD, verify the SID, etc, but validation still fails, with no real explanation why

Comment: Can you log in as that user on the Windows server?

Comment: our policy says no interactive login for service accounts so I haven't tried

Comment: If you can quickly change that, test it out, see the results, and revert you might save some time.  It could be something with AD auth.

Comment: I can't make changes in AD.  I did just try to map a network share to the machine, using the service account to connect, and that failed, so I think something is wrong with the accounts.  I can logon to the server using my domain account, I can map drives, etc, just these two seem to have a problem.  I sent it back to the AD guys and asked them to take a look at the account.

Comment: Good call.  It could be several things from wrong password given to you to Kerberos, authing server and ad replication, etc. etc.

Comment: Or have the AD guys install SQL Server. If they don't trust you to log on to the server interactively, no offense, but why are they trusting you to install SQL Server there?

Comment: Aaron, I log on to the server, using my account, and have local admin rights.  By policy our service accounts are not supposed to be able to logon interactively.

Comment: Do you have another service on that machine where you can swap the account with this "unproven" account to see if it works? Assuming there are no differences in privileges, it's a quick way to see if the service account your AD crew gave you is functional. Also, from your pasted log, there appears to be a password validation failure 

(13) 2016-06-30 15:44:03 Slp: UserSecurity.ValidatePassword -- user validation failed, attempting an interactive logon in case cached credentials are present

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I heard back from the domain admin.  The account was accidentally restricted much more then called for.  I'm not sure what restriction was removed but the installer now works fine.